# Indonesian with Japan visa travelling to South Korea

Tags: visas, japan, south-korea, indonesia

My friend is an Indonesian and would like to travel to South Korea, he holds a Japan technical intern visa.

Will he be exempt from a South Korean visa? If not, how should I get the South Korea visa?

Comment: Are you trying to get a visa for Him or for you. In one part of the question you ask about whether he needs a visa. You then ask how you'd get a visa if he doesn't have a visa exemption. I tidied the question up a bit in an edit, but i wasn't sure what you meant there.

Answer (score 2):

Per TIMATIC, an Indonesian citizen needs a visa unless they hold a visa for certain other countries<sup>1</sup>, Japan not included. To obtain a toursim visa (probably B2), the person trying to visit should contact the nearest South Korean embassy.

<sup>1</sup> Australia, Austria, Belgium, Canada, Cyprus, Czech Rep., Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, USA or United Kingdom